# how to extract numeric value out of text ,along with converting it into number in Cypress

Tags: jquery, parsing, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-custom-commands

hi folks as i am new into this cypress and UI automation I need your help in resolving current scenario
i have a grid like this [image]
i have created a `custom command` in `support\commands.js` below is my code which take `OrderID` as parameter and read the `Freight info` from ui but it has lot of `nested div` tab for padding hence i use `parents()` tag to reach the specific index row

```
Cypress.Commands.add('readFreightInfo', (OrderID) => {
  return cy.get('.simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)')
    .contains(OrderID)
    .parents("div[role='row']")
    .find('div')
    .eq(2)
    .invoke('text')
})
```

but the text it is returning is '\n 65.88'
what i needed
i needed the number part only i.e. 299.88 in `Number type`

as it was a generic method for validation i was using earlier

```
cy.readFreightInfo(10250).should('eq', 65.83)
```

but now I want to assert it as the returning value of `custom command`  should lies `between 60 and 70`

what i have tried so far

i have tried using both the workaround mentioned on this answer

[solution link i have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223836/extracting-parts-of-a-text-in-cypress)

Comment: It looks like your selector is incorrect. Showing the html code for the table will help with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value from custom command like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('readFreightInfo', (OrderID) => {
  cy.get('.simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)')
    .contains(OrderID)
    .parents("div[role='row']")
    .find('div')
    .eq(2)
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
      return cy.wrap(+text.replaceAll('\n ', '')) //returns 65.83 as number
    })
})
```

And then in your test, you can do like this:

```js
cy.readFreightInfo(10250).then((numValue) => {
  cy.wrap(numValue).should('eq', 65.83) //direct assert
  cy.wrap(numValue).should('be.gte', 60).and('be.lte', 70) //greater than equal to 60 and less than equal to 70
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.trim()` removes line terminatiors from both ends of the text.

Also, shortcut for getting the row - use `.contains('[role="row"]', OrderId)`.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('readFreightInfo', (OrderID) => {

  cy.contains('div[role="row"]', OrderID)
    .find('div')
    .eq(2)
    .invoke('text')
    .then(text => parseInt(text.trim()) )
})

cy.readFreightInfo(10250)
  .should('be.within', 60, 70)
```

Ref [string.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string and returns a new string, without modifying the original string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) **and all the line terminator characters** (LF, CR, etc.).